# How to Diplay block of numbers of given input numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to display a  block of numbers of the input with input times

basic web pages

```
var j= "";
var n=prompt("Enter the size of the box");
for(var i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
   document.write(i +"<br>");
}
```

if the given input is 5 the **output** should be as follows:

```
o/p
12345
12345
12345
12345
12345
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exact problem are you having?

Comment: Try using two loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var j= "";
var n=prompt("Enter the size of the box");
var x = [ ...Array(n*1+1).keys() ].join('').substring(1);
for(var i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
   document.write(x +"<br>");
}
```

Comment: Sure but not sure about whos downvoting your answers. What loops and conditions are you interested in??

Answer (score 1):

`prompt()` method only returns a string. So, first you need to convert the string to a number using `parseInt()`

```js
    var num = prompt('Enter the size of the box: ');
    num = parseInt(num);
    for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      for(let j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
        document.write(j+' ');
      }
      document.write('</br>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem .

```
var j= "";
var n=prompt("Enter the size of the box");
for(var i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
 for(var j = 1; j<=n ; j++ ){
     document.write(j);
 }
 document.write("<br>");
}
```

Comment: Give the reason behind downVote .. Please be gentleman in this gentlemen's community ..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new to programming and this example wants to teach you nested loops.
You'll have to split up your task to the smallest possible steps and think about what is happening in your loops. The best way is to work "inside-out".

- So first you think about what is a single step you want to do: printing a number.
- After that you'll think about how often you want to print it in a row.
- After that you'll think about how you want to separate the rows.
- In the final step you'll think about how many rows you want to print.

The code above will work for you now, but if you don't think about it, you'll fail at the next similar problem.

Give a man a fish and you'll feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you'll feed him for a lifetime! ;-)